# Selecting data from four tables at once

Tags: mysql, select

```
+----+-------+---------+------+--------+--------+
|q_id|q_title|q_content|q_date|q_status|q_author|
+----+-------+---------+------+--------+--------+
| 1  |varchar| text    | int  |   int  |   int  |
+----+-------+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

This is the first table: **questions**. 
**Tags** table has this structure:

```
+------+--------+---------------+
|tag_id|tag_name|tag_description|
+------+--------+---------------+
| int  |varchar |     text      |
+------+--------+---------------+
```

And the third table (**question_tags**) has this structure:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | tag_id | q_id |
+----+--------+------+
|int |  int   | int  |
+----+--------+------+
```

The last table (**users**) has this structure:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | username |password|
+----+----------+--------+
|int | varchar  |varchar |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I used to select the data with this query:

```
SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( tags.tag_name ) 
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON q_author = users.id 
LEFT JOIN question_tags 
ON questions.q_id = question_tags.q_id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = question_tags.tag_id 
GROUP BY questions.q_id
```

But it doesn't satisfy my needs anymore. Also please notice that in the **question_tags** table you can have more than one tag per question and I want to get all tags and their IDs.

Comment: In what way does it not satisfy your needs?

Comment: It returns a string with the tag names I want to get also the tag_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is correct. If you want the IDs of tags:

```
SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(tags.tag_id,'=',tags.tag_name))
```

How do you want the output to look?

Answer (score 0):

***Try this code it should work as expected***

```
 $tblQry = 'SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT( tags.tag_name ) FROM questions 
                     LEFT JOIN (tags, question_tags, users)
                     ON (tags.tag_id=question_tags.tag_id 
                     AND questions.q_id=question_tags.q_id)
                     WHERE users.id = "'.$user_id.'"';
```